# Is there a way to specify the address at which some assembly code should be placed?

Tags: gcc, assembly, embedded, gnu, bare-metal

I'm currently working on some baremetal code for the Raspberry Pi, and I'm attempting to place the interrupt vector table--implemented in gnu assembly--at address 0. I previously wrote the table in C and used the section attribute and linker script to specify where the table should be placed.

Is there a similar method, or another method, available in gnu assembly to store the table at address 0?

Comment: Commonly you do this with the linker script.

Comment: GNU assembler has a `.section` directive that works the same way as `__attribute__((section))` in GCC